# Display posts grouped by post type in taxonomy.php

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have two Post Type('newpost' and 'book') associate with custom taxonomy(newcategory)(writer1, writer2, writer3...)

I have need to show each custom post at separate style with Post term.

My code is :

```
 $post_type = array('newpost','book');
 //echo get_query_var('term');

     foreach($post_type as $postType)
     {
 $args = array(
    'post_type' => $postType,
    'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => rawurldecode(get_query_var('term'))
                )
            )
    );

 $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
 if($my_query->have_posts()) :
     while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
     {

//I got all the post here by //echo '<h1>'.the_title().'</h1>'; but i have need it separately.          
//Here I want to display all the term of the custom post separately  

      endwhile;
 endif;


     }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Short version

Within your loop call: `get_template_part( 'loop', get_post_type() );`

You need now a `loop.php` as general fallback template (the default view).
You can generate as many post_type specific templates as you need, e.g. `loop-newpost.php` and `loop-book.php`.

But you are overthinking it a bit and adding another query on top the main query (page load?). You can add full template support to your theme with the following.

## A better apporach

**Add your CPTs**.

```
function add_my_custom_post_type() {
    $args = array(
        'menu_position' => 8,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-post',
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'query_var' => false,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'new-post',
            'feeds' => true,
            'pages' => true,
            'with_front' => true,
        ),
        'taxonomies' => array(
            'author'
        ),
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'thumbnail',
            'excerpt'
        )
    );
    register_post_type( 'newpost', $args );
    $args['labels']['name'] = __('Books', 'my_textdomain');
    $args['labels']['all_items'] = __('All Books', 'my_textdomain');
    $args['labels']['singular_name'] = __('Book', 'my_textdomain');
    $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'book';
    register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
add_action('init', 'add_my_custom_post_type');
```

**Add your custom taxonomy**.

**Attention:** author is a slug used by WordPress, so you need to be creative: `tax_author` for the taxonomy name & `query_var` and `the-author` for the slug.

```
function add_my_custom_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'tax_author',
        array(
            'newpost',
            'book'
        ),
        array(
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Authors', 'my_textdomain' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Author', 'my_textdomain' ),
                'menu_name' => __( 'Author', 'my_textdomain' ),
            ),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'the-author',
                'with_front' => true,
                'hierarchical' => false
            )
        )
    );
}
add_action('init', 'add_my_custom_taxonomy');
```

**Add the CPT to the main queries** in questions with the `pre_get_posts` hook

```
function add_my_custom_post_type_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home() && !is_admin() /* No filtering of CPTs in the backend */) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('newpost', 'book') );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_custom_post_type_to_query' );
```

**Edit**: You don't need this for taxonomies, but if you want to add your CPT to the main query, use this hook. — *Thanks to @Pieter Goosen for the clarification.*

Within your `taxonomy-tax_author.php` template file you can now **use the main loop**:

```
if (have_posts()) while (have_posts()):
    the_post();
    get_template_part( 'loop', get_post_type() );
```

You need now a `loop.php` as general fallback template (the default view).
You can generate as many post_type specific templates as you need, e.g. `loop-newpost.php` and `loop-book.php`.

**Update**:
If you want to order the query by post_type you need to hook into the `pre_get_posts` again

```
function order_my_custom_taxonomy( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_tax('tax_author') && !is_admin() /* No filtering of CPTs in the backend */) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'type' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_custom_post_type_to_query' );
```

For detailed information about how to filter and order follow the provided links.

### More information about:

- Post Type: [Custom Post Types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types)
- Taxonomy: [Custom Taxonomies](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies)
- Action Hook: [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)
- Loading Templates: [wptherightway.org](http://www.wptherightway.org/en/templates/index.html)
- Order By: [type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

Comment: `post_type` is set to `any` on taxonomy archives, so you do not need to include custom post types on taxonomy archives, it is done by default ;-)

Comment: if (have_posts()) while (have_posts()):
    the_post();
    get_template_part( 'loop', get_post_type() );


//At there if I want to show post_type='book' first and after it want to show post_type='newpost' type how can control  the loop. And how get the post custom fields created by using plugin.

Comment: updated (thx to @PieterGoosen). vj tester i added your request, but please read about pre_get_posts at the codex to get other ways to manipulate the main query.